# Model value is null but why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

I've been working on a web application for uni to handle travel bookings in C# and have have completely hit a brick wall trying to overcome this issue.

When attempting to open the webpage 'FlightDB', I receive the following error:

```
An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_z0gc0uw3.dll but was not handled in user code
```

In FlightDB's view, the value of `Model` is `null`. I'm fairly certain this is what is causing the error, but I can't understand why.

Here's the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebsiteAssignment.Models.FlightsTbl>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Choose Flights:";
}

<h2>FlightDB</h2>
<table>

    @foreach (var item in Model) //model = null
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FlightId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Departing_Airport)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Arriving_Airport)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Departure_Flight_Time)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Return_Flight_Time)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Available_Space)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

And the controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebsiteAssignment.Models;

namespace WebsiteAssignment.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        private FlightDBEntities1 db = new FlightDBEntities1();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            int currentHour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
            ViewBag.Message = currentHour < 12 ? "Good Morning" : "Good Afternoon";

            return View(db.FlightsTbls.ToList());
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult ApplicationPage()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ApplicationPage(Application newApplication)
        {
            var WebsiteAssignment = new List<Application>();

            if (Session["WebsiteAssignment"] != null)
            {
                WebsiteAssignment = (List<Application>)Session["WebsiteAssignment"];
            }

            WebsiteAssignment.Add(newApplication);

            Session["WebsiteAssignment"] = WebsiteAssignment;


            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("FlightDB");
                //return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        public ActionResult FlightDB()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

If somebody could please help me understand I would be extremely grateful. Almost pulling my hair out over this.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4):

You must pass in a model for `Model` to have a value. For example:

```
public ActionResult FlightDB()
{
    return View(new List<WebsiteAssignment.Models.FlightsTbl>());
}
```

`View()` has a number of overloads, one of which allows you to simply pass in a model. The MVC framework will then search for a view matching the name of the method (`FlightDB`, in this case) to send the model to for rendering.

Comment: Thank-you for such an informative, clear answer. Really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem. It can get confusing, because in this scenario you create an object just to display nothing. The object (empty list, in this case) is then destroyed after the page is rendered. Finally, if a form is submitted that happens to generate an object of the same type, it's a completely new object. It can be counter-intuitive to create the 'empty' objects when rendering forms. You might choose to conditionally test for `null` in your view instead, depending on your needs.